# INotifyPropertyChanged with Model and ViewModel

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, mvvm

My ViewModel has a collection of model. I have few questions in this regard.

1 - If I only implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in ViewModel, when the property of the model is modified in the view, how to notify the model? Should I impletement the interface in both model and ViewModel?

2 - If I want to use LINQ in ViewModel, I have to create the collection of the model with `List<T>`, couldn't be `ObservableCollection`, yes?

3 - Where should I operate the database? In ViewModel or other places? For example, I add an instance in the view, I want to add it to the database, where should I execute the LINQ command to insert it?

Thanks.

Comment: can u list down questions one by one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The instance of the Model that you are modifying in the View, will be updated automatically due to DataBinding.(hope i understood correctly what you are asking)
2. Linq can be executed on instances of types that implement IEnumerable, IQueryable. You CAN use Linq on ObservableCollection
3. You should have a business layer that handles the CRUD operations, and call it from the ViewModels as needed.

Comment: Hi @dutzu, thanks for your reply! The first question, if the viewmodel only contains a collection of model. Should I have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface? ObservableCollection has already impletement this interface. If the collection is the List<T>, I implement the interface, when the list has changed, it will notify the viewmodel, but if only a property of model changed, the list doesn't change, does it will notify the viewmodel?

Comment: If you have in the viewmodel a List<T> the only thing the notify event will trigger is if the instance itself has changed. But what you want is to notify if something inside the collection has changed, so please use ObservableCollection for that. The second thing, if you need to notify the view that a property of a model instance in the collection has changed - The model has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged also for this to work.